# TCP Socket with custom service type

Tags: c#

I'm a new C# developer (I'm from obj-c), and I was using objective-c to create a TCP socket with a type (`initWithDomain:@"local." type:@"_nameOfServer._tcp." name:@"nameOfServer" port:1234`) and I want to create a TCP socket (with C#) that uses the "type" value (I want it because I develop an iPhone application that searches TCP servers with the type value).

Any idea (class, code, etc.)?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at documentation and been stumped on something?

Comment: Isn't type a Bonjour-specific concept?  You'd probably have to find a way to register your endpoint with Bonjour separately.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this it not possible to reproduce in a .Net based socket server. This `type` parameter is specific to the `NSNetService` class in Cocoa.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNetService_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNetService/type

Comment: Well, just because that's specific to cocoa doesn't mean it can't be done, but I'd certainly need an explanation of what effect that has on the communications protocol. It's unclear to me what the effect of the service type aspect of the "type" means. What is "_nameOfServer" and what effect does that have on the socket?

Comment: @Pete, the `type` parameter means the HTTP service on TCP (ex: `_http._tcp.`).

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But what EXACTLY does that mean in terms of the socket? HTTP is a protocol, not a socket type. So what effect to setting the type on have on the socket.